# How to mark checkbox in Freemarker template

Tags: java, html, css, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker template (java) and I need to show checked checkboxes. I expect to see a checkbox marked with a regular checkmark (unicode "U+2714"), but instead of I see that my checkbox marked with question mark (U+003F). I need a regular checkmark, or even "X" is good, but not question mark "?". My code now is:

```
<#list labels as checklabel> 
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checklabel" name="checklabel" checked="true">
<label for="checklabel">${checklabel}</label>
</div>
</#list>
```

Maybe somebody knows what I do not do right and can help me?

Comment: A plain `<input type="checkbox">` is shown with question mark when it's checked in? I guess that's some CSS issue, combined with a font issue (the font used misses the required character).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't use the same `id` and `name` for multiple `input`-s. Because of the `#list` loop, you will possibly have multiple `input`-s.

Comment: @ddekany
 A plain <input type="checkbox"> is shown with question mark when it's checked in? Yes.  
Also I forgot to say that output file is pdf, that means I enter my data like html in freemarker template, next I send this template to some service that make conversion to pdf and in pdf file that I get from such service I see this problem. I also see that developers of that service use Apache Pdfbox library, maybe such library by default shows marked checkboxes in such way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:-

```
<input type="radio" id="checklabel" name="checklabel" checked>
```

you have to write only `checked` and the type to `radio`.